# Delphi indy get page content

Tags: delphi, indy

I have seen a lot of examples online, but I cannot understand why my code doesn't work.

I have an url that looks like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/confirm.php?user=USERNAME&id=THEID
```

`confirm.php` is a page that does some checks on a MySQL database and then the only output of the page is a 0 or a -1 (true or false):

```php
<?php

//long code...
if ( ... ) {
 echo "0"; // success!
 die();
} else {
 echo "-1"; // fail!
 die();
} 

?>
```

My Delphi FireMonkey app has to open the URL above, passing the username and the id, and then read the result of the page. The result is only a -1 or a 0. This is the code.

```pascal
//I have created a subclass of TThread
procedure TRegister.Execute;
var
  conn: TIdHTTP;
  res: string;
begin

  inherited;

  Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
       ProgressLabel.Text := 'Connecting...';
    end
  );

  //get the result -1 or 0
  try

    conn := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      res := conn.Get('http://www.domain.com/confirm.php?user='+FUsername+'&id='+FPId);
    finally
      conn.Free;
    end;

  except
    res := 'error!!';
  end;

  Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin

      ProgressLabel.Text := res;    
    end
  );

end;
```

The value of `res` is always `error!!` and never -1 or 0. Where is my code wrong? The error caught from `on E: Exception do` is:

> HTTP/1.1 406 not acceptable

Comment: Well it appears `error!!` only occurs when an exception is raised. You should be reading the exception and let us know the exact exception this is actually raising. Otherwise, all we can do is guess, and there are millions of possible guesses we could make.

Comment: So your except block should be more like `except on E: Exception do begin res := 'EXCEPTION: ' + E.Messages; end; end;` Please do this and then edit your question to provide the exact exception which is being raised.

Comment: Also if you are under ARC there is no need to Free the object

Comment: @AlbertoMiola I forgot! You are right

Comment: @JerryDodge So I should review my http headers?

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi Yes. The error is related to the various media acceptance headers (`Accept`, `Accept-Charset`, `Accept-Language`, `Accept-Encoding`). The error means there is a mismatch in what the client asks for and what the server is able to produce.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution using `System.Net.HttpClient`. I can simply use this function

```
function GetURL(const AURL: string): string;
var
  HttpClient: THttpClient;
  HttpResponse: IHttpResponse;
begin
  HttpClient := THTTPClient.Create;
  try
    HttpResponse := HttpClient.Get(AURL);
    Result := HttpResponse.ContentAsString();
  finally
    HttpClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This works and gives me -1 and 0 as I expected. To get an example of a working code I have tested this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

function GetURL(const AURL: string): string;
var
  HttpClient: THttpClient;
  HttpResponse: IHttpResponse;
begin
  HttpClient := THTTPClient.Create;
  try
    HttpResponse := HttpClient.Get(AURL);
    Result := HttpResponse.ContentAsString();
  finally
    HttpClient.Free;
  end;
end;

function GetURLAsString(const aURL: string): string;
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    Result := lHTTP.Get(aURL);
  finally
    lHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;

begin

 Memo1.Lines.Add(GetURL('http://www.domain.com/confirm.php?user=user&id=theid'));
 Memo1.Lines.Add(GetURLAsString('http://www.domain.com/confirm.php?user=user&id=theid'))

end;

end.
```

The first function works perfectly but Indy raises the exception *HTTP/1.1 406 not acceptable*. It seems that Indy cannot automatically handle the content type of the page. Here you can see the REST Debugger log:

[image]

Comment: Indy instead didn't work and it was bad because it always gave me HTTP/1.1 406 not acceptable. This solution is better.

Comment: Indy works just fine. The error means you are simply not configuring it correctly to work with your PHP page, or vice versa.

Comment: "*It seems that Indy cannot automatically handle the content type of the page*" - Indy does not have a problem with the page's type. It is PHP that is reporting the error because it is having a problem handling Indy's request.

Comment: So you are telling me that there is a problem with my php page content type? From what I have seen in your comment above Indy accepts basically everything. When I set header("Content-Type: text/plain") at the beginning it works perfectl with System.Net but not with Indy.

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi You should seriously consider what Remy has to say, he is one of the authors of the Indy library. Your problem is that Indy is following the HTTP rules :-)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Error `406 Not acceptable` typically means that the server is not able to respond with the content type the client wanted. Both the Server and Client need to appropriately use the MIME type as you need. In this case, your client's `Accept` headers should provide the desired type of response, and your server should also be responding with the same. In your case, the `Content-Type` will most likely be `text/plain`.

So long story short, your client is expecting a MIME type which the server does not explicitly return in its response. The problem could be on either side, or perhaps both.

1. Your Client's `Accept` headers must provide the MIME type(s) you expect and need. Specifically `Accept`, `Accept-Charset`, `Accept-Language`, `Accept-Encoding`. By default in Indy `TIdHTTP`, these headers should accept essentially anything, assuming these headers haven't been overwritten. The `Accept` header is by default set to `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q‌​=0.8` where the `*/*` opens the door for any MIME type.
2. Your Server's Response's `Content-Type` must be one of the provided MIME types, as well as the format of the response as also desired by the client. It is likely that your HTTP server is not providing the appropriate `Content-Type` in its response. If the server responds with anything in the `*/*` filter (which *should* mean everything), then the client will accept it (assuming the server responds with `text/plain`). If the server responds with an invalid content type (such as just `text` or `plain`), then it could be rejected.

Comment: So if the server is having a header("Content-Type: text/plain") the client must be able to read a text/plain as well. Correct?

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi Your client's `Accept` headers also need to reflect the same.

Comment: By default, `TIdHTTP.Request.Accept` is set to `'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'`. This puts a higher preference on HTML, but still tells the server that anything is acceptable. Make sure the PHP server is sending back a proper Content-Type.

Comment: @Remy Indeed. That's essentially what I'm trying to say, just more generally about HTTP in a broad scope, not just Indy. Most likely yes, the server is returning the wrong content type.

Comment: +1 idk who downvoted this. Btw @RaffaeleRossi you should setup the header at the beginning of the PHP file, it looks like you're sending a "naked" document with the default content.